# How to use css modules (react semantic ui) in create react app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using react semantic ui and I want to add margin left and margin top for Table component (i.e align it in center) I also want to reduce the cell size inside Table but my css is not working why so ? Do I need to add any css loader or scss loader ? I am not able to understand why is my CSS code not working ?

Note: Table component has a prop called className and I want to make use of className prop and add custom styles. Link: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#types-pagination

updatePage.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Icon, Label, Menu, Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import faker from 'faker';
import s from './updatesPage.css';

const UpdatesPage = () => (
    <Table celled className={s.updateForm}>
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>URN number</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Parish</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Last Updated</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Notes</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>

      <Table.Body>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.name.findName()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.random.number()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.address.streetAddress()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.date.weekday()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.random.words()}</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.name.findName()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.random.number()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.address.streetAddress()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.date.weekday()}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{faker.random.words()}</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
)

export default UpdatesPage;
```

updatePage.css:

```
.updateForm {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Above code is working i.e javascript is working but the CSS is not working why so ? See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQJ0b.jpg I am not able to see any margin top, left for table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with line import css. While import the css no need to give the module name for it. Just change the import line as below, it  will work

```
import './updatesPage.css';
```

Also change the code for className as below

```
<Table celled className='updateForm'>
```

Like sematic ui take priority while setting the css. So you need to change the priority in css add **!important**.

```
.updateForm {
    margin-top: 100px !important;
    margin-left: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: I am using CSS modules in create react app.

Comment: it is not working. Note: I am using react semantic ui and Table component has a className prop

Comment: No it doesn't work. Note: I am using react semantic ui -> https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#types-pagination

Comment: Please take screenshot again and upload it here.

Comment: While saw this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/e3bsCvf I have noticed that css set but priority is taken by semantic UI it's not getting updated. So I have edited the answer please check it. You can also follow steps answered by @Ryan C just add !important in css

Answer (score 2):

In order to use CSS modules with create-react-app you need to rename your css file to updatesPage.module.css.

You can find documentation for this in the “Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet” portion of the [user guide](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

Comment: Do I need to make any changes in webpack.config file in node modules -> react scripts ?

Comment: No, CRA using the file naming convention of *.module.css to indicate use of css modules, otherwise it interprets it as a regular css file.

Comment: I saw your updated answer and I am doing same thing but it is not working any idea how to reduce size of table and align it ? margin left and margin top not working